# Не загружаются данные из базы данных в сгенерированные jquery ячейки таблицы

Tags: jquery

Друзья есть такая проблемка - в сгенерированые ячейки таблицы не загружаются данные из базы данных. Просьба к знающим, посмотрите что я делают не так?

```
function fetchUsers() {
    Parse.initialize("lp");
    Parse.serverURL = 'http://46.101.79.85:1337/parse';

    var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
    var query = new Parse.Query(User);
    query.equalTo("approved", false);
    query.find({
      success: function(results) {
        alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");
        // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
        var rows = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          var object = results[i];
          var row = '<tr>' + '<td>' + object.get('username') + '</td>' + '</tr>'+
                    '<tr>' + '<td>' + object.get('diploma') + '</td>' + '</tr>'+
                    '<tr>' + '<td>' + object.get('qualification') + '</td>' + '</tr>'

        rows = rows + row;

        }


        $('#mainTable').append(
          '<tr><td class="name"></td>' +
          '<td class="seeDiploma"></td>' +
          '<td></td>' +
          '<td>' +
              '<div class="acept"></div>' +
              '<div class="reject"></div>' +
          '</td></tr>'
        );


      },
      error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте где-нибудь переменную `rows` :)

```
$('#mainTable').append(
      '<tr><td class="name"></td>' +
      '<td class="seeDiploma"></td>' +
      '<td></td>' +
      '<td>' +
          '<div class="acept"></div>' +
          '<div class="reject"></div>' +
      '</td></tr>' + rows
);
```

Comment: спасибо огромное. Я новичек, не увидел, очевидного))))